Using ANT to copy a list of files
I'd like to deploy a subset of my classes in /src-core/classes/*
copying them to another folder src-partial where I have a package.xml declaration of the subset
  <types>
    <members>classA</members>
    <members>classG</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
  </types>

With this buidfile I'm able of copy the whole folder.. but how can I read the contents of package.xml and copy only the classes classA and classG? (the buildfile must be common for all the team members and they only change de package.xml)
    <target name="deploy-parcial">
      <echo level="info">Copying src-core/classes to src-parcial folder</echo>
      <copy todir="${basedir}/src-parcial" >  
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/src-core" includes="classes/*"/>  
      </copy> 

      <echo level="info">Deploy package in src-partial</echo>
        <sf:deploy
            username="${sf.username}" 
            password="${sf.password}" 
            serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
            checkOnly="${sf.checkOnly}"
            deployRoot="${basedir}/src-parcial/"
            rollbackOnError="true">           
        </sf:deploy>
    </target>


The copy task can't read values directly from an XML document, but you can parse its contents into properties using the xmlproperty task and then use those properties as includes. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html
